# 22.04LTS does not end booting process

Tags: boot

I have 22.04 LTS. No idea if it's appropriate, but before I had a powered USB switch (10 ports) connected because one external disk needed power. I removed that disk and also the USB switch (after some things are done) and I did reboot my system again.

Now it does not end the booting process and my system is always looking for usb 1-8

dmesg|grep usb shows:

```
    [    2.514991] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
    [    2.669382] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0026, bcdDevice= 0.02
    [    2.669462] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    5.513741] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 4
    [    5.955026] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
    [    6.108271] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0026, bcdDevice= 0.02
    [    6.108280] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    6.168731] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 5`
    [...]
    [...]
    [   15.815023] usb 1-8: new low-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
    [   15.947070] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [   16.191076] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
    [   16.715070] usb 1-8: new low-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
    [   16.716235] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
    [   16.923003] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
    [   17.135059] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 21, error -71
    [   17.263097] usb 1-8: new low-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
    [   17.264301] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
    [   17.475037] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
    [   17.682996] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 22, error -71
```

At around device number 22, I pressed CTRL+C to get the normal command prompt and I can use my system normally.

Further lsusb shows me:

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:55af SanDisk Corp. Extreme Pro 55AF
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 31b2:0010 KTMicro KT USB Audio
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**LATER**: As **user** [**YtvwLD**](https://askubuntu.com/users/111985/ytvwld) wrote in one of his useful comments the error msgs where related to a bluetooth adapter. Which brought me to remove BT adapters from the system, reboot and it was working again.

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title. Instead, accept the answer that helped you by clicking on the gray check mark beside it.

Comment: Sorry for that and thx for editting

Answer (score 0):

These messages are not part of the booting process, they just appear when you plug in (or remove) USB devices.

If they occur by themself, the device, the cable or the USB port on your computer might be broken.

To figure out, what of this is happening, try disconnecting all USB devices and plug them in one by one until the messages appear. (If they don't, it was just a bad connection.)

Comment: no usb connected, only a screen and an ethernet cable. after reboot again these messages: 'usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71'. Also tried another kernel (just in case of), but the same errros. device or usb port broken is not obvious since the device (Beelink U59)  is only 3 days old

Comment: [8087:0026](https://ubuntu.com/certified/component/817) seems to be a Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: thanks @YtvwlD. How do I get rid of the BT adapter i.e. how do I remove it from my system

Comment: You didn't specify what kind of device you've got. You may be able to just disconnect it from your motherboard (or reconnect to fix the connection) or you may have to disable it in the firmware setup.

Comment: AFAIK I dont have a BT device connected at my Beelink U59, Meanwhile I removed some BT packages and now it is working fine again !

However when I enter: apt list --installed|grep bluetooth, I get:

libbluetooth3/jammy,now 5.64-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatically]

Can I remove it as well without consequences